# Regex select word after specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I capture a word just after specific word in regex, I have to select everything between **from** - **to** and after to so there will be two capturing groups.

Example:
"From London to Saint Petersburg" I wanted to extract `London` `Saint Petersburg` from above string.

Im stuck with this code here, my current regex selecting `to Saint Petersburg` i wanted to get rid word `from` and `to` from the selection.

```
/(?=to)(.*)/i
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can capture the two groups you need and then use `match` to extract them:

```js
s = "From London to Saint Petersburg"

console.log(
  s.match(/From (.*?) to (.*)/).slice(1,3)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just use `split()` and use `/From | to /`, it will return an array containing split values

```js
var str = "From London to Saint Petersburg";
var arr = str.split(/from | to /ig);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code doing what you asks for:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
 var strIn = "From London to Saint Petersburg";
 var regEx = /^From\s(.+?)\sto\s(.+?)$/;
 var arrResult = regEx.exec(strIn);
 var strOut = "Original:" + strIn + "<br>Result:<br>";
 strOut += "1. " + arrResult[1] + "<br>";
 strOut += "2. " + arrResult[2];
 document.write(strOut);
</script>
</html>
```

Place this in a document. Open it with a browser. Here is how the result looks like:

```
Original:From London to Saint Petersburg
Result:
1. London
2. Saint Petersburg
```

Hope it helps!